# How to load semi structure data from a table to file in iics

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, iics

need help

I have a table called customer and it ishaving below fields

Customer_id | payload | created_dt | modified_dt

Here payload is json format and remaining fields are relational.

I want to convert json data into relational and load all the data into target including customer_id, created_dt, modified_dt

I'm using hierarchy parser transformation but it accepts only one field as input.

Comment: what is the error you got ? it will accept whole JSON data as 1 column and output multiple columns from that.

Comment: Yes correct it is taking payload json field as input and giving relational data as response but how can we process remain fields from source like customer_id, created_dt, modified_dt

Comment: Data looks like below customerid, createdate, modifieddate, payload)
VALUES
    (1, '2023-06-01', '2023-06-15', '{"name": "John Doe", "email": "johndoe@example.com"}')

Comment: Process the payload and do a join back to the other fields.